# script runs fine, but can't get pytest to work

Tags: python-3.x, unit-testing, csv, pytest

Trying to learn pytest, the following script runs fine, but with pytest it fails as it can't the find csv file.

```
import csv

def load_data(file):
    mast_list = []
    with open(file) as csvfile:
        data = csvfile.read()
        phone_masts = data.split('\n')
        columns = csv.reader(phone_masts, delimiter=',')

        for row in columns:
            if len(row) > 0:
                mast_list.append(row)
    return mast_list
```

I am trying just to get something working, so trying to test that the function is returning a list type, but it says no csv file found. I'm sure there are plenty of other issues but I'm trying to do one bit at a time. Here is the test:

```
import pytest
import mobile_phone_data

def test_column_count():
    file = 'Mobile Phone Masts.csv'
    assert load_list() == type(list)
```

Why does the script work on it's own but the test fail because it can't find the csv file?

Comment: Is 'Mobile Phone Masts.csv' reachable from your test module? Eg what would `os.path.exists('Mobile Phone Masts.csv')` say?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is actually a bit surprising you get a file not found error: you create a function under one name and try test a different function, that is an error to start with.

I call your first listing `foo.py` and modified your test script as following:

test_foo.py

```
from foo import load_data

def test_column_count():
    file = 'spam.csv'
    assert isinstance(load_data(file), list)
```

There is also a a file called `spam.csv`, all three files are in the same folder. `pytest` runs this test and it passes.

Other issues in your code:

- your `csv` import does unnecessary things - you do not have to split a newline the hard way, use reader parameter instaed
- `isinstance` should be used for type checking
- you might be creating a temp file for unit testing and destroying it
- the initial function `load_data()` can be split in two: one that reads a file and the other that parses its content, which shoud eventually make it easier to test.

Comment: Thank you. Yes you are right, I finally spotted that, the file is called mobile_phone_data and the first function is called load_data. Thank you for the input about other issues, actually these points were the gold in your comments.

Comment: Glad you enjoy the unit testing endeavour, in case you dig deeper, you might want to review notes below and some associated links: https://github.com/mini-kep/guidelines/blob/master/testing.md

Comment: You are welcome to raise issue / do a pull request in a repository for the link above - there are obviously more questions to cover about unit testing.